# Limit Vertical Scrolling Sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to stop my scrolling vertical sidebar at about 400px down the page otherwise it keeps on going forever.

1. What detection do I need to put in place?
2. How do I halt #sidebar? (currently the top margin is manipulated)?

Full Code:

```
//Scrolling sidebar
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        };

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top + 150) {
            $("#morecontent").fadeOut(1000);
        } else {
            $("#morecontent").fadeIn(1000);
        }

    });
});
```